# Serving image files using streaming rather than static image file serving

Tags: performance, servlets, grails

I have a Grails web app. Currently I'm serving static image files to my users. I saw this post on StackOverflow that discussed a solution about serving images as stream to hide the source of it. My question is, doesn't that have some trades-off such as putting load on the server since it needs to open a socket in order to stream it to the user v.s just serving it as a static file ?

```
// controller action
def displayGraph = {
    def img // byte array
    //...
    response.setHeader('Content-length', img.length)
    response.contentType = 'image/png' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << img
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

You could then access your image in the src of an  tag like this:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'displayGraph')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.outputStream << img
response.outputStream.flush()
```

This is not streaming if you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media

It's just using Java OutputStream to provide response content - which is done on the server and response is returned to the client. No socket is kept open.

Comment: Thanks. So this can hide the source of the image and also doesn't take up connections or sockets ? No performance caveat ?

Comment: No. There is no difference between this way and serving static images in terms of performance of getting a resource. But static images could be cached better that's the downside of using this approach.

Comment: If I store my static images of user profile somewhere outside the web-app area, can I still use the static image link to serve it to the user but doesn't allow them to access that directory directly ?

Comment: Sure. But if you need some advice for this, you should post new question.